# Most elegant way to implement animated "sliding panels"

Tags: animation, javascript

I'm attempting to implement a similar animated "sliding panels" effect as the [Aveda](http://www.aveda.com) website.

I'm a little overwhelmed by all the options and Javascript libraries that are available.  And a little confused after examining the Aveda website code.

Any recommendations as to how to approach this task please?  Which Javascript/Effects library would be most suitable?  I don't have any allegiance or greater experience in one library over the other.

My requirements are:

- Cross-browser compatibility (of course)
- Simple & Elegant implementation
- Don't want to re-invent the wheel
- Ability to animate and to be activated by mouse-clicks (like the Aveda front page)
- Dynamic (don't want to have to modify javascript as more 'panels' are added)

My first impressions would be to use Scriptaculous - Effect.Move, but I'm aware that there are ready-made implementations like [Spry's](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/slidingpanels/SlidingPanelsSample.html).

Any words of wisdom and suggestions would be greatly appreciated by this Javascript newbie.

Prembo.

Comment: Does bandwidth matter? Prototype/Scrip. is quite heavy compared to jQuery.

Comment: Not too much.  Out of curiosity - how much heavier is Prototype/Scriptaculous, compared with jQuery?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions...  Will investigate the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like http://www.davidmassiani.com/horinaja/

It can use the mousewheel aswell as the links to scroll between panes, and it's available for script.aculo.us and jQuery.

I would recommend the latter as it is lightweight and easy to learn/handle.

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/ is a good tutorial for this using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I do like the way Aveda implemented that effect.  They are using prototype/scriptaculous, and it is a custom implementation.

The Aveda effect is called a carousel.  The Aveda carousel scrolls to the next element on a timer and has a nice non-linear transition.

+1 to Deefjuh, I think that Horinaja would do what you want and be easiest to implement.

If you want more of a challenge, I've used PrototypeUI ( http://www.prototype-ui.com/ ) Carousel to do a series carousels for project (e.g. http://teacher.scholastic.com/products/classmags.asp ) But the dot indicator controls had to be custom programmed.